# defining member functions within __init__

Tags: python, class, init

Is it possible to define member function in a python class within the **init** method?

I am thinking something similar to setattr or through a lambda

```
class Engine(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Engine, self).__init__(self)
        self.__class__.__call__ = lambda self, x: x
```

does not work, but

```
 class Engine(Base):
        def __init__(self):
            self.__class__.__call__ = lambda self, x: x
            super(Engine, self).__init__(self)
```

does, why is that?

Comment: You should add `self` to your `lambda` expression like this: `lambda self, x: x`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Like this:

```
class Engine(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__class__.__call__ = lambda self, x: x

a = Engine()
print(a(42))  # it prints 42
```

Comment: but then its a class method and not an instance function, isnt it? The problem I am facing is that Engine is actually subclassing a base class which requires to be passed a callable to its constructor. So I wanted to implement the call operator of the derived class and then pass it as self to its base class

Comment: No, it's not a class method. For the class method it's necessary to use `classmethod` decorator. I added two lines to my answer to show how it works.

Comment: thank you, However, the base class requires to be passed a callable and so I wanted to pass it the derived class with a call method which has been defined while being in the init method. Why do I have to do this before calling super? I adapted the code above